# Multiple Cucumber report has been encoded to base64

Tags: cucumber, bdd, maf

Currently, I have an issue that when run a file feature for BDD (behavior driven development)
Then after I  go into the report to see the detailed but it's show me like this [image]

In last month, I saw it still show as normal, easy to see the report, but now it's changed
This is my reference in my package.log file

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "runFeature.sh",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber-js -f json:report/cucumber_report.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/event-hubs": "^5.11.2",
    "@azure/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob": "^1.0.1",
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^10.0.1",
    "@ln-maf/api": "^2.0.5",
    "@ln-maf/core": "^2.0.2",
    "@ln-maf/mysql": "^2.0.2",
    "@ln-maf/validations": "^2.0.4",
    "chai": "^4.3.10",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "flat-object-keys": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.5.0",
    "pako": "^2.1.0",
    "utf8": "^3.0.0",
    "uuid-validate": "^0.0.3"
  }
}
```